# Mqtt Client Paho close issue (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, mqtt

I have:

```
MqttAsyncClient mq;
   ...
   mq = new MqttAsyncClient(myServer1,"app1");
   mq.connect();
   ...
   //(1)
   //doing something with mq (pub/sub)
   ...
   mq.disconnect();
   mq.close();
   //(2)
```

Now I am using a Monitoring Console and I see:

- In (1), 3 Mqtt threads:
  MQTT REC, MQTT SND and MQTT Call
- In (2), 2 Mqtt threads:
  MQTT SND and MQTT Call
- After further seconds only 1 thread
  MQTT CALL

The CALL thread will never be stopped. 
How come ?

Comment: do you have the full code of multithreading with mqtt

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the the asyncclient had been disconnect before  invoking close() method, otherwise the thred of async will blocking forever. you can deal like this(just same with @Tom&@Mehmet Ince):

```
IMqttToken token = mq.disconnect();

int count = 0;
while (count++<5) {
  if (token.isComplete()) {
    mq.close();
    break;
  }
  try {
    Thread.sleep(2000l);
  } cath(Exception e) {
    //TODO
  }
}

if (count > 5) {
  mq.disconnectForcibly();
  mq.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use should use : `MqttClient client = new MqttClient...` then call `client.connect();`

Because, It will invoke the code : `aClient.connect(options, null, null).waitForCompletion(getTimeToWait());`  (you can check the source code)

so it can make sure the connection is really completed.